# show force close error in android phone

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

when i run my app in emulator its work perfectly fine but when i run it in my android phone it show force close error.

Here is my logcat

```
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=47623KB, Allocated=39485KB)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:626)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:730)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.example.fatwallet.MyAdapter.setDrawable(MyAdapter.java:83)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.example.fatwallet.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:69)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2334)
08-03 02:04:36.602: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1409)``
```

line no 83 is...

```
setDrawable(image, dataObj.getImageId());
```

and line no 69 is..

```
private void setDrawable(ImageView image, String drawableName) {
        AssetManager manager = image.getContext().getAssets();
        InputStream open = null;
        try {
            open = manager.open(drawableName+".jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
            // Assign the bitmap to an ImageView in this layout
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (open != null) {
                try {
                    open.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: This is an OOM exception (out of memory), you might be loading a bitmap that is too big. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to map a big file into memory. Try to set this in your manifest:

```
<application 
             android:largeHeap="true">
    . . .
</application>
```

However it is a discouraged solution. From official documentation:

*Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.*

Link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl).

Answer (score 0):

Since phones have different memeory sizes my suggestion to you is reduce the image size and try Again. [Bitmap createScaleBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))